# Text file formatting using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark, use Scala 2.10 and Spark 1.6.
Trying to format Input_file_001.txt as below,

Input_file_001.txt:

```
Dept 0100 Batch Load Errors for 8/16/2016 4:45:56 AM 

Case 1111111111
Rectype: ABCD 
Key:UMUM_REF_ID=A12345678,UMSV_SEQ_NO=1
UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID 

Case 2222222222
Rectype: ABCD 
Key:UMUM_REF_ID=B87654321,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2
UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID 
NTNB ERROR  :Invalid Value                          NTNB_MCTR_SUBJ=AMOD

Case 3333333333
Rectype: WXYZ 
Key:UMUM_REF_ID=U19817250,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2
UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID
```

Output file as

Input_file_001.txt

```
case~Rectype~key,Error
1111111111~ABCD~UMUM_REF_ID=A12345678,UMSV_SEQ_NO=1~UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID
2222222222~ABCD~UMUM_REF_ID=B87654321,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2~UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID,NTNB ERROR  :Invalid Value                          NTNB_MCTR_SUBJ=AMOD
3333333333~WXYZ~UMUM_REF_ID=U19817250,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2~UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID
```

I was trying to achieve it like below,

```
val source = sc.textFile("Input_file_001.txt")
val fileread = source.filter(x => ! x.startsWith("Dept"))).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(z => z.trim)
```

above code giving me Array[String], not able to take it forward.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize `wholeTextFiles` api to read the input file, which will read the input file as a line ==> `(filename, whole text as one line)`. Then you can manipulate the whole text line and turn it to your desired output. Finally you can add the `header` and save it to a file

```
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("path to Input_file_001.txt")
val finalRdd = rdd.flatMap(tuple => tuple._2.split("\nCase ")
  .map(record => record.replace("\nRectype: ", "~").trim
    .replace("\nKey:", "~").trim
    .replace("\nUMSV ERROR  :", "~UMSV ERROR  :").trim
    .replace("\nNTNB ERROR  :", ",NTNB ERROR  :").trim)
).filter(record => !record.startsWith("Dept"))
val header: RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(Array("case~Rectype~key,Error"))
header.union(finalRdd).saveAsTextFile("path to ouput file")
```

you should have the following output

```
case~Rectype~key,Error
1111111111~ABCD ~UMUM_REF_ID=A12345678,UMSV_SEQ_NO=1~UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID
2222222222~ABCD ~UMUM_REF_ID=B87654321,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2~UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID ,NTNB ERROR  :Invalid Value                          NTNB_MCTR_SUBJ=AMOD
3333333333~WXYZ ~UMUM_REF_ID=U19817250,UMSV_SEQ_NO=2~UMSV ERROR  :UNITS_ALLOW must be > or = UNITS_PAID
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thank you Ramesh for your input. I tried your solution, it is giving me same format as source file but just replaced with ~ in each row. I am trying to achieve output file format as each field separated by ~ and row end with new line so I can build external hive table on top of it. Also can I add source file name as field in output file ?

Comment: isn't your source file as in the question? If not then the solution won't work,

Comment: ohh, I got it. I was running it locally on IntelliJ with partial code. I just tried running .jar on cluster. It is giving expected result now. You are awesome. Thank you.

Comment: great to hear that @vin :) and thanks for the acceptance